# Windows 10 performance is really slow and it freezes randomly

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, freeze

From the last 10 days my explorer crashes or stops responding, sometimes with the screen going black with only a cursor, after I updated my windows 10 to the latest version 20H2 and removed the third party anti-virus software, explore is working better than before but still it is slow, it takes more time to boot up than it should, files and folders stops responding and takes longer to open than they should, video stops playing, when I attach files from PC to Gmail or other sites the tab which is created for uploading files suddenly hangs, and also my VS code programs are running really slow.

I troubleshooted my PC , I even reset Windows 10, keeping files, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

- Any busy process in task manager?
- Also look in Resource Monitor as see which process is writing most to your disk.
- your disk might be defective.
- In Task manager, in the Performance tab, look and the disk section. Is latency close to 100%? I had this problem on some Virtual machine and it was caused by changes in disk/controller configuration (SCSI ID/ SCSI ctrl address and device naming)...never really got to the bottom  of it, I just changed ID, address and name, and somehow it solved the strange problem. I know you cannot use this solution directly, by it be a hint to where to look.